# trying to remove rows with backslash characters with pandas but getting unwanted double quotes added

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find and then remove rows that contain a backslash in my csv file. I tried this:

```
   df[df["query"].str.contains("\\")==False]
```

but this results in the error:

```
    sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

The only way I can avoid this error is with,

```
    df[df["query"].str.contains("\\\\")==False]
```

but this adds an extra double quote to everything in the file and does not remove the row.

What is the expression to identify rows containing a backslash and then remove the row?

EDIT:
This is an example csv file I'm reading from:

```
    collection,label,groups,query
    Model,general,Mob,WHERE * SAYS ("trying out app"|| "trying out app"|| "trying out app's")
    Model,general,Bun,WHERE * SAYS ("bundle"|| "bundles"|| "bundled"|| ""tv package""|| ""internet package""|| ""tv and internet package""|| "internet 2 bundle"|| "internet 2 package"|| "tv 2 bundle"|| "tv 2 package"|| "phone 2 bundle"|| "internet 2 phone"|| "internet 2 tv") AND NOT * SAYS ("\"EEOS|| Internet|| TV & Phone Solutions\""|| "\"EOOS|| Internet|| TV\""|| "\"phone solutions\"")
```

Per the answer below, I edited my code and now the row is removed.

```
    data = pd.read_csv('so.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df[~df["query"].str.contains("\\", regex=False)]

    df.to_csv('sores.csv')
```

However in the result, double quotes are added:

```
    ,collection,label,groups,query
    0,Model,general,Mob,"WHERE * SAYS (""trying out app""|| 
    ""trying out app""|| ""trying out app's"")"
```

Comment: this example is not reproducible without the file..

Comment: I added a sample csv file to the post so it can be reproducible. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Was this CSV exported by MySQL, by any chance?  It uses different defaults and standards compared to `pd.read_csv`. The problem can be fixed by simply specifying a different quote char: `pd.read_csv('temp/test.csv', quotechar="'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas' `.str.contains` uses regular expressions by [default](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Add `regex=False` to parameters:

```
df[~df["query"].str.contains("\\", regex=False)]
```

Also note that instead of comparing to `False` it's better to negate the result (`~` in the beginning)

E.g.:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({"query": ['positive: \\', 'negative']})
> df
         query
0  positive: \
1     negative

> df[~df['query'].str.contains("\\", regex=False)]
      query
1  negative
```

Comment: why does it 1)still not remove the row 2)add double quotes to the result?

Comment: @topplethepat can you write a reproducible example?